# output json file for each yaml file input

Tags: python, json, yaml

in python want to output json for each yaml file input.
have this so far and unable to write to same json file as yaml filename as input.

```
import yaml
import json
import datetime
import os, glob

path = './test/json'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.yaml')):
   with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        json_file = 'filename.json'
        with open(json_file, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(yaml.safe_load(f), outfile)
```

this outputs to one json file instead of separate files.

Comment: You're naming your JSON file the literal string `filename.json`. If you want a different filename for each iteration of the loop, you're going to need to use a variable in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import yaml
import json
import datetime
import os, glob

path = './test/json'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.yaml')):
   with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        json_file = filename.replace('.yaml', '.json') # change the file extension
        with open(json_file, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(yaml.safe_load(f), outfile)
```

Comment: Have a followup question, if want to save the output files to /tmp directory and delete json files after I do some transformation, how to do that?

Comment: that's a whole separate question, if you make another question and link it here I can answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742480/copy-files-to-temp-directory-and-delete-those-at-the-end 
just posted the question. Thanks!