# copy files to temp directory and delete those at the end

Tags: python, json

Looking to use temp directory in python code, I'm doing some transformations on the files. generating json from yaml..want to copy those to temp directory while generating those and also rm those at the end.

Comment: you want to load the copy the yaml files to the directory? couldn't you just load the yaml as a dictionary and output as json all within python without having to create a temp folder?

Comment: while outputting as json want to output to temp directory so will be used for transformations and after done with that will delete these jsons in temp folder

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you may need all from within python and no temp files. This will create a json file with yaml data for each yaml file in a directory. If you need to do more processing to the loaded dictionary from yaml, you can do that too pretty easy by combining these functions:

```py
import os
import glob
import json
import yaml

def jsonify(data):
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # print pretty json formatted for debugging and examples

def open_yaml(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader) # load objects as strings so they work with json

def write_json(path, data):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # remove indent arg for minified

def file_yaml2json(path, ext='.yaml'):
    data = open_yaml(path) # dictionary of the yaml data
    write_json(path.replace(ext, '.json'), data) # write new file with new extension

def get_all_files(path, ext='.yaml'):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(path, f'*{ext}')) # find with files matching extension

def dir_yaml2json(path, ext='.yaml'): # default to find .yaml but you can specify
    files = get_all_files(path)
    for file in files:
        file_yaml2json(file) # run for each detected yaml file

dir_yaml2json('./') # convert all the files in the current directory
```

If you take out all the comments there are really only a few functional lines here, just split them up in functions for ease of use